# Shucked WD Elements 8 TB not recognized

Tags: hard-drive

I shucked 2 new WD Elements 8 TB drives. Both worked prior to shucking and I just connected one to the controller again and it still works. But when I connect the disks like internal hard drives, neither of them are recognized. `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` just don't list them. I had them connected to my server where they were going to be used and to my desktop computer.

Is there a way to use them without the USB controller? There are several YouTube videos of how to shuck the WD Elements drives, so I assumed they worked just like regular hard drives after shucking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be another case of the 3.3 V pin shutting the HDD down. I came across this when googling the problem: Apparently, some HDDs shut down when they receive power over the 3.3 V pin. Taping that pin over makes the HDD work. I hope that random package tape of the previous tenant I found when I moved here works well electrically because I don't own electrical tape. ^^

If you look at the pins, there are the S-ATA pins and the power supply pins. The S-ATA pins are fewer. Turn the disk so that the S-ATA pins are on the left. Then the pin to tape over is the third pin from the left of the power supply pins.

Comment: You **really** should invest in that electrical tape.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean for other uses or for this? Do you think my disks will start randomly shutting down?

Comment: The 3.3V pin sounds like an attempt to discourage shucking.

Comment: I bought electrical tape and will replace my insulation as soon as the current copying operation finished. Feels weird to replace something that currently works and prevents a system from shutting down, though.

Comment: Be careful with any kind of tape, especially electrical or package tape. It's a great insulator but the adhesive deteriorates and makes a mess. You don't want it to bleed onto other contacts, and you may have a messy residue to clean up if you ever decide to remove it, and it can get on the connector contacts.  Virtually any kind of non-metallic tape will be an adequate insulator, and the adhesive really needs to hold up just long enough to get the connector on.  After that, the connector will hold it in place.  I'd be tempted to use something like Removable Magic Tape, or even nail polish.

Comment: @fixer1234 Does that imply that I shouldn't remove the old tape and apply electrical tape?

Comment: I'd remove the existing tape and if there's any residue, clean the surface with acetone (if you don't have it, pick up a small bottle of nail polish remover anywhere), but be careful not to get it on plastic parts (circuit board material is fine), or use adhesive remover, then alcohol to remove any oily residue. Then use either nail polish (it's strong, flexible and resists chipping and peeling, and you can remove it if you ever need to), or something like Removable Magic Tape.  The removable tape has a different kind of adhesive that minimizes contact and doesn't tend to flow.

Comment: @fixer1234 I did what you said: I removed the tape, cleaned the pins with q-tips, then cleaned them with q-tips dipped into nail polish remover and afterwards regular q-tips (3 iterations). Then I applied one layer of nail polish, waited 10 to 15 minutes, applied another layer of nail polish, waited 4 hours, and connected the hard drives again. However, now sometimes they are recognized by the OS, sometimes one of them, sometimes none. Changes every reboot.

Comment: So I just took the hard drives out of the server again to measure the conductivity of the nail polish. Something I probably should've done before I put the disks into the server. Well, this might be the problem right there: https://i.imgur.com/R7hhWlu.jpg So I guess I'll remove the nail polish and apply the electrical tape.

Comment: It looks like the nail polish is too thick, and has ridges that can catch on the connector.  It needs just a thin, smooth layer.  But I definitely wouldn't use electrical tape.  Clean off the nail polish so you have a flat, smooth surface.  Then use a tape with adhesive that doesn't flow or turn to goo.

Comment: Hmm, I think just managed to fry the data on the RAID. Luckily, I have it backed up but it's gonna be a pain to get it back onto it. I used electric tape and even restarted the server 6 times to make sure that the disks are always recognized. Then I started the sync process and the drives failed. I'll revert to packaging tape and will keep it like that until it fails, at which point I can try a single layer of nail polish. But I don't feel like doing that again because it'll take time to dry and thus far packaging tape was the only thing that worked.

Comment: If you have a Dremel tool, you could grind out those contacts, or just grind a slit across the contact where it enters the connector.  :-)